# Should I use HTML5 Canvas or CSS3 Sprites to animate objects for a game?

Tags: animation, html, canvas

I'm in the process of starting to build a strategy game (think warcraft) for the web. I've been doing research on HTML5 Canvas and CSS3 sprites and still can't decide which technology to use.

The game won't be completed for another 6 months.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Brilliant idea BTW. Starcraft / Warcraft could be easily ported to a the web.

Comment: Just a FYI: there's a StackExchange site for games development @ http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you probably hear so frequently... "It Depends..." ™

My suggestion would be consider the feel of the application you're after. If you are trying to build a very graphically rich, mostly-images application, then I would use Canvas. However if you are trying to animate some graphics, but have the page remain and behave more "Web-like", mixed with other HTML content, I'd give CSS3 a try.

Two additional points:

- Currently, Canvas is better supported than CSS3 animation/sprites.
- If you use Canvas you're going to be implementing your own render loop and animation code (or making use of a 3rd partly library). Your code create animation by compositing the various layers of each frame, applying movement, and repeating. You can't simply say "move this image a little to the right". You'll have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The EA web game "Lords of Ultima", as dull as it is, is an excellent example of a WarCraft-styled (well, it's more city building as there are no visible units) overworld, with animations and everything, built on a pure HTML and CSS sprite base. It looks and performs well and I think the square block box-model nature of HTML suits that kind of tile based design, especially since a lot of the image processing (embed an `<img>` or a `<div>` with a background, change background-position for animation) and click/mouse handling is done for you in simple html.

If you do go canvas you have to manage that yourself which will greatly increase the complexity and dev time. You'll have more control of minor elements and improved performance, but then you'll also lose (if it's at all important), greater backwards compatibility with older browsers. So it depends on how complex your design is and what kind of performance you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use Canvas. If you use CSS sprites to build a game, then you are going to make a lots of `<div>`'s which performs operations on the DOM, which may slow down and also have a lots of focus and compatibility problems.

It may pay off to trade the development time for performance on `<canvas>`, by the assumption of "A code will be maintained forever".

I think CSS3 sprite system takes more time to develop, because you need to handle browser compatibility.

Browsers like IE 8 (8 or 9?) are using GPU to accelerate graphics, which lets you get the free lunch of Moore's Law.

Answer (score 0):

There's pros and cons to both. Currently, Canvas is better supported then is CSS3, but you said that your game won't be done for another 6 months, by then the support for CSS3 could be much much better. There's also a lot of other variables here, such as: What browser will the game be viewed on? How advanced are the graphics you need to animate? etc... I would say that canvas would be better for support of the current generation of browsers and for gaming graphics, however CSS3 would be quicker, but wouldn't even come close to the support or graphics handling. But it doesn't seem like your in a rush to get it done.

Basically:

Canvas: Graphics, current support in users browser

CSS3: Speed of development

Ether will work. But for now I would use Canvas. However, 6 months in the tech world is an eternity, things could be a lot different then.